# Entity relationship is not recognied by the join column

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I am trying to find all results in the `Monthly` table that have an association with a `Category`.
I did my research and the following code should theoretically speaking work but somehow is throwing the following **Error** `Notice: Undefined index: joinColumns in...`

The tables are joined by a join table and the keys used is `category_id` and `monthly_id` tried to run the query using `category_id` but still doesnt work and throws another error.

When I run `orm:validate-schema` it seems all to be working fine. What am I missing?

**From the Monthly Entity**

```
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Bnk\Entity\Category", inversedBy="monthly")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="months_categories",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="monthly_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $category;
```

What am i missing so that I can find all `Monthly` that are associated with a given `Category`?

```
$months = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->getRepository('Bnk\Entity\Monthly')
    ->findBy(
        array(
            "category"=>$category->getId()
        )
);
```

Comment: are you sure it fails on this specific relation? try and removing this relation config and see if the error disappears.

Comment: @NDM if i do findAll it works fine

Comment: findBy cannot handle a many-to-many relation.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343533/using-entityrepositoryfindby-with-many-to-many-relations-will-lead-to-a-e-no

Comment: And consider renaming Monthly#category to categories.  Makes it clear that you dealing with an array of categories.

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe forget to initialize your ArrayCollection?
In your entity constructor function you always have to initialize them.

So at the top of your class:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
```

and your constructor function:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->category= new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Comment: Doctrine entity creator does that for me automaticaly